# Padding in proof of space hierarchy theorems

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Referring to the Wikipedia proof :

Wikipedia proves the [space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) using the following language:
$$ L = \{ (\langle M \rangle, 10^k) : \text{$M$ does not accept $(\langle M \rangle, 10^k)$ using space $f(|(\langle M \rangle, 10^k)|)$} \}. $$

Why do we need the padding with $10^k$? How does it help us in the proof, and where does it fail if we do not consider it?

I assume that the same reasoning would be valid also for the nondeterministic version.

Comment: It is important because we are talking about asymptotics

Comment: This is explained here: https://lin-web.clarkson.edu/~alexis/PCMI/Notes/lectureB09.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that we consider instead the language
$$ L = \{ \langle M \rangle : \text{$M$ does not accept $\langle M \rangle$ in space $f(\langle M \rangle)$} \}. $$
We want to show that $L \notin \mathsf{SPACE}(o(f(n))$, that is, that if $M$ uses space $o(f(n))$ then $L(M) \neq L$. This should be the case since $$\langle M \rangle \in L \Leftrightarrow \langle M \rangle \notin L(M).$$
But is this really true? According to the definition of $L$, $\langle M \rangle \in L$ iff $M$ does not accept $\langle M \rangle$ *in space $f(\langle M \rangle)$*. It could be that $\langle M \rangle \in L$ and $M$ accepts $\langle M \rangle$ *using more than $f(\langle M \rangle)$ space*. The latter could actually happen, since we are only guaranteed that $M$ uses space $g(n)$ for some function $g(n) = o(f(n))$, which does not preclude $g(|\langle M \rangle|) > f(|\langle M \rangle|)$ at the *particular* value $|\langle M \rangle|$.

Adding the padding fixes this issue: it cannot be that $g(|(\langle M \rangle, 10^k)|) > f(|(\langle M \rangle, 10^k)|)$ for all $k$, since this would contradict $g(n) = o(f(n))$.